# Off-screen drawing GDI+

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem - I need to draw two png files, one on the other. When I do it usual way, there is a "blinking" effect (first image overdraws the second one for small time period). I use GDI+ library and my WM_PAINT handling looks like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, & ps );
    displayImage(firstImage, hwnd);
    displayImage(secondImage, hwnd);
    EndPaint( hwnd, & ps );
    break;
}
```

displayImage function:

```
void displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd)
{
    RECT myRect;
    BITMAP bm;
    HDC screenDC, memDC;
    HBITMAP oldBmp;
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;

    GetObject(mBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff;

    bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    screenDC = GetDC(mHwnd);
    GetClientRect(mHwnd, &myRect);

    if (mBmp == NULL)
        FillRect(screenDC, &myRect, WHITE_BRUSH);

    else
    {
        memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
        oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, mBmp);
        AlphaBlend (screenDC, 0, 0, myRect.right,myRect.bottom, memDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight, bf);
        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        ReleaseDC(mHwnd, screenDC);
    }
}
```

Loading files to variables:

```
HBITMAP mLoadImg(WCHAR *szFilename)
{
   HBITMAP result=NULL;

   Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(szFilename,false);
   bitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &result);
   delete bitmap;
   return result;
}


firstImage = mLoadImg(L"data\\img\\screen.png");
secondImage = mLoadImg(L"data\\img\\screen2.png");
```

I've heard that I should do a off-screen drawing. How should that look like?

Comment: create a memory dc, load your bitmap into that, then get the window dc and call bitblt with the memorydc as a parameter

Comment: Note that your ReleaseDC should be outside the `else` clause.

Comment: @jhbh: That doesn't address this question. It's asking for alpha-blending two images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need all of that. You can use GDI+ directly:

```
static Gdiplus::Image *firstImage;
static Gdiplus::Image *secondImage;

case WM_CREATE: // or WM_INITDIALOG if it's dialog
{
    firstImage = new Gdiplus::Image(L"data\\img\\screen.png");
    secondImage = new Gdiplus::Image(L"data\\img\\screen2.png");
    return 0;
}

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    Gdiplus::Graphics gr(hdc);
    gr.DrawImage(firstImage, 0, 0);
    gr.DrawImage(secondImage, 0, 0);//<== this will draw transparently

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this code is still drawing 2 images back to back with possible flicker (like your original code). Use double-buffering in `WM_PAINT` so that only one `BltBlt` is done. Simply change to:

```
if (msg == WM_PAINT)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);
    HGDIOBJ oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    FillRect(memdc, &rc, WHITE_BRUSH);
    Gdiplus::Graphics gr(memdc);
    gr.DrawImage(firstImage, 0, 0);
    gr.DrawImage(secondImage, 0, 0);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    return 0;
}
```

As for the original code:

```
void displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd)
{
HDC hdc = GetDC(mHwnd);
...
}
```

You should change the function declaration to `void displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HWND mHwnd, HDC hdc)` then you can pass the `hdc` directly from `WM_PAINT`

Answer (score 3):

First, change displayImage to take the HDC and RECT from the caller instead of the HWND.

```
void displayImage(HBITMAP mBmp, HDC hdc, const RECT &myRect)
{
    if (mBmp == NULL)
        FillRect(screenDC, &myRect, WHITE_BRUSH);
    else
    {
        BITMAP bm;
        GetObject(mBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);

        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
        HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, mBmp);

        BLENDFUNCTION bf;
        bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
        bf.BlendFlags = 0;
        bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff;
        bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

        AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, myRect.right, myRect.bottom, memDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bf);

        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
    }
}
```

Then, in the caller create a compatible DC and bitmap.  These are your off-screen space for doing the compositing.  Make the calls to displayImage with this new DC.  This will compose the PNGs offscreen.  Finally, blit the composed result to the actual window DC in one go.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    RECT myRect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &myRect);

    // Create an off-screen DC for composing the images.
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbmpMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, myRect.right, myRect.bottom);
    HBITMAP hbmpOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmpMem);

    // Compose the images to the offscreen bitmap.
    displayImage(firstImage, hdcMem, myRect);
    displayImage(secondImage, hdcMem, myRect);

    // Blit the resulting composition to the window DC.
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, myRect.right, myRect.bottom,
           hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Clean up the offscreen stuff.
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmpOld);
    DeleteObject(hbmpMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Finally, if you're still seeing a flash of the background color, see Pavan Chandaka's answer.

Comment: Great! It works. Note: there should be `SRCCOPY` insead of `SRC_COPY` in the BitBlt function.

Comment: Re `SRCCOPY`: That's what I get for typing from memory.  Edited answer to fix.  Note that you could also cache the extra memory DC and bitmap for better efficiency if you paint frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Handle "WM_ERASEBKGND" message by your self.

Actually before loading the second image two things happen.

1. WM_ERASEBKGND is triggered first to fill the image area with, whatever current windows background color is.
2. WM_PAINT to render action.

Documentation says to avoid blink/Flickr, provide a default handler for "WM_ERASEBKGND".

Below is the link, go to "A Control That Doesn't Flicker". You have an example too.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969905.aspx

Comment: It seems like you didn't comprehend what causes flicker, and how to prevent it. The flicker in this question is caused by rendering two images back to back, so your proposed solution doesn't apply. I find it a bit unnerving that I have to waste my reputation on you, just because you don't care enough. I haven't seen a single helpful answer from you, ever. Before attempting to answer the next question make sure you understand it fully, and that you **know** the answer.

Comment: Boss I achieved that 983 reputation in a month. I think you have difficulty in understanding me. And you are not here to bossing around..

Comment: Seeing that you got yourself the [Peer Pressure](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=6866309) badge in your first month already, maybe it's not just me that thinks your contributions are questionable. (This proposed answer certainly completely misses addressing the issue.)

Comment: There are so many people like you in "C++" tag. Who simply down votes. I stopped attempting that tag completely even though I know answers.

Comment: Alright then, since you claim to know the answer, would you mind updating this one to explain, **why** providing a default handler for `WM_ERASEBKGND` solves the OP's issue, and how?

Comment: He is loading the second image. I have two steps in my answer, saying what happens when he load the second image. The first step explains it. The windows proc will repaint the image area first by using WM_ERASEBKGND message. Did you open the link provided and read it?

Comment: Loading an image will not cause any rendering to happen. It reads a chunk of bytes off the disk, and stores it in a block of memory. So your explanation doesn't make any sense. Now if you meant to write that in between **rendering** the first and the second image, that's still bogus. There's nothing in the OP's code that would cause the system to generate a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message in between displaying those images. The OP's issue, and the issue outlined in your link are different.

Comment: I should say rendering.....  His code is not trying to render second image? If not rendered How he would see flickering.

Comment: Now look, **test** your assessments. Write up a small test case, and observe, whether the system generates a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message in between rendering those two images. If it doesn't, delete your answer (as then it would obviously be wrong).

Comment: I have lot of PROD work to do, I can't do it now. I might have deleted long back. But "Adrian McCarthy" mentioned my name in his answer. Thats why I am keeping it, even though I lose two points.